# Radio Buttons with different ng-models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

Hi I have three radio input fields with same name but different ng-models:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio"name="deliveryAddress" 
           ng-model="CC.OrderDetailsModel.IsNewDeliveryAddress">
    Save address to profile for use on future orders
</label>

<label>
    <input type="radio"name="deliveryAddress" 
           ng-model="CC.OrderDetailsModel.ExistingDeliveryAddressUpdate">
    Update Existing Delivery Address
</label>

<label>
    <input type="radio"name="deliveryAddress" 
           ng-model="CC.OrderDetailsModel.UseForThisOrderOnly">
    Use address only for this order
</label>
```

I want to make when input is check that has value `true` otherwise `false`

Of this three `ng-model` only one can have `true` value. Something like this:

```
CC.OrderDetailsModel.IsNewDeliveryAddress: false,
CC.OrderDetailsModel.ExistingDeliveryAddressUpdate: false,
CC.OrderDetailsModel.UseForThisOrderOnly: true
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest to use **only one variable** for all your radio button, as [adviced by Angular for `input[radio]`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D):

```
<input type="radio" name="deliveryAddress" ng-model="deliveryAddress" value="newDeliveryAddress"/>
<input type="radio" name="deliveryAddress" ng-model="deliveryAddress" value="existingDeliveryAddressUpdate"/>
<input type="radio" name="deliveryAddress" ng-model="deliveryAddress" value="useForThisOrderOnly"/>
```

Here is just change the `value` set in ng-model. You can then do your treatment based on this value.

## [Try it on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5TMRQp1m36IC2iHSYLNy?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

As you [explained in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42952544/4927984) if you want to keep your logic, you can add a `ng-change` event on your inputs to set values:

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="deliveryAddress" 
          ng-model="CC.OrderDetailsModel.IsNewDeliveryAddress"
          ng-change="change(CC.OrderDetailsModel.IsNewDeliveryAddress)">
   Save address to profile for use on future orders
</label>

<label>
   <input type="radio" name="deliveryAddress" 
          ng-model="CC.OrderDetailsModel.ExistingDeliveryAddressUpdate"
          ng-change="change(CC.OrderDetailsModel.ExistingDeliveryAddressUpdate)">
   Update Existing Delivery Address
</label>

<label>
   <input type="radio" name="deliveryAddress" 
          ng-model="CC.OrderDetailsModel.UseForThisOrderOnly"
          ng-change="change(CC.OrderDetailsModel.UseForThisOrderOnly)">
   Use address only for this order
</label>
```

The `change()` function will set variables to `false` and then the selected one to `true`:

```
$scope.change = function(changed) {
    CC.OrderDetailsModel.IsNewDeliveryAddress = false;
    CC.OrderDetailsModel.ExistingDeliveryAddressUpdate = false;
    CC.OrderDetailsModel.UseForThisOrderOnly = false;
    changed = true;
}
```